# adding new column to a pyspark dataframe based on other column

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I would like to add a new column to a dataframe based on another column using `WHEN`. I have the folowing code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, when
df2=df.withColumn("test1",when(col("Country")=="DE","EUR").when(col("Country")=="PL","PLN").otherweise("Unknown"))
```

but I get the error:
`'Column' object is not callable`
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **typo** in your statement.

- `otherweise` change to **`otherwise`**

---

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("DE",),("PL",),("PO",)],["Country"])
df.withColumn("test1",when(col("country") == "DE", "EUR").when(col("country") == "PL", "PLN").otherwise("Unknown")).show()
#+-------+-------+
#|Country|  test1|
#+-------+-------+
#|     DE|    EUR|
#|     PL|    PLN|
#|     PO|Unknown|
#+-------+-------+
```